# using the pipe and word count (wc) then dress the result

Tags: awk, grep, wc

I'd like to dress the output of a grep I'm doing.

Imagine a file text.txt with a lot of text.  Then I do the commands:

```
grep fred text.txt | wc -l
grep bob text.txt | wc -l
grep james text.txt | wc -l
```

I get the output:

```
12
3
4
```

What I would like to print as the output is:

```
fred was found on 12 lines.
bob was found on 3 lines.
james was found on 4 lines.
```

How can I do that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In a shell script, using `grep -c` to count the lines:

```
for name in fred bob james
do
    echo "$name was found on $(grep -c $name text.txt) lines."
done
```

This runs half as many processes.  This assumes you don't end up wanting to search for a name with spaces (`'lucy anne'`) or quotes (`"o'reilly"`) — if you need to be more general in the names you'll handle, you also need to be more careful about using double quotes around `$name` in the command substitution.

However, you could scan the file once using `awk` (or Perl or Python, or …) which could be a big saving if the file is huge:

```
awk '
    /fred/  { count["fred"]++ }
    /bob/   { count["bob"]++ }
    /james/ { count["james"]++ }
   END      { for (name in count) print name, "was found on", count[name], "lines." }
   ' text.txt
```

That's similar to the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63958575/15168) by [RavinderSingh13](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5866580/ravindersingh13) but it counts only lines where the names occur, not the total number of occurrences (so if a line contains "bob was bobbing on the water all discombobulated", it will count 1 line, not 3 occurrences).  Note that the search is neither case-insensitive ("Bob" won't be counted), nor constrained to match 'words' for any reasonable definition of word.  These comments apply to the `grep` solution too, but you can also use options such as `-i` for case-insensitivity (from POSIX) and `-w` for matching words (GNU `grep` and some others, such as BSD and hence macOS X).

Answer (score 4):

You could try following in `awk`(not tested since no samples provided), in case you are ok with `awk`, you need not to run many `grep` + `wc` commands it could be done in a single `awk` program itself.

```
awk '
{
  a["fred"]+=gsub(/fred/,"&")
  a["bob"]+=gsub(/bob/,"&")
  a["james"]+=gsub(/james/,"&")
}
END{
  for(i in a){
    print i" was found on "a[i]" lines."
  }
}' Input_file
```